# laravelの画像保存先を変更したい

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

laravelのデフォルトディレクトリではstorage/app/publicの中に画像が保存されますが、public/imagesファイルに画像の保存先を変更したいのですがどうすれば良いのでしょうか？

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14211712549

Answer (score 1):

こちらの内容が有用かと思います。
[How to upload files in Laravel directly into public folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44577380/how-to-upload-files-in-laravel-directly-into-public-folder)

上記リンクの回答にある手順を翻訳しただけになりますが、以下の手順でいかがでしょうか？

1. `config/filesystems.php` の `disks` に以下を追加する

```
'public_uploads' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root'   => public_path(),
],
```

2. ファイルを保存する

`$request->file('img')->storeAs('images', 'image.png', 'public_uploads');`
※画像が `img` として送られてきていて、それを `public/images` に `image.png` という名前で保存する場合